# Send Mail using PHP failing

Tags: php, sendmail

I am using the same php code I have always used to try and send a form via email and I am getting this message:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]:
>   Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in
>   php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   sendMailSuscribete.php on line 44

this are lines 40 - 54:

```
$header .= "From: $email" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Return-Path: $email" . "\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $header)){
    //Message sent!
    redirect("http://www.domain.com/suscribete.html");
}else{
    // Display error message if the message failed to send
    echo "
    <div class=\"MsgError\">
        <h1>Error&hellip;</h1>
        <p>Disculpa <b><?=$name;?></b>, tu mensaje fall&oacute; en ser enviado. Por favor vuelve a intentar.</p>
</div>";
}
```

I already checked using `phpinfo()` and I know that the smtp is set to localhost and the port it uses is 25 so I really have no idea what the error may be.

**Update**
I forgot to say it is running on a Windows server and this php file is the one I've always used for Unix servers, should it contain something different?

Comment: Are you *running* a SMTP server on localhost port 25?

Comment: Try testing it with a Gmail SMTP server or something to eliminate the code being at fault.

Comment: To do that I should just try to use it via Gmail? (adding the account) or is it differently?

Comment: No, it would involved updating your SMTP server settings in the php.ini file or through ini_set. I'll post a proper answer here to help you test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mail` cannot send e-mails directly (at least not on Windows), it needs an SMTP server. There is no SMTP server running on the host on which the PHP-Script is being executed. Solutions are:

1. Use a library that can send e-mails directly using SMTP, like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Swiftmailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org/) ([github repo](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer)).
2. Edit the php.ini directives to point to a SMTP server that accepts e-mails from you. Ask your hosting provider if you do not know which one to use.
3. Set up an SMTP server on localhost.

Point 1. is a good idea, because those libraries provide abstractions that make it unnecessary to deal with low level stuff like putting MIME messages together correctly. Point 2. is probably the least trouble. I advice against Point 3. unless you are serious about administering an e-mail server by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using an external SMTP mail server, for example, Gmail's? If you have a Gmail account, you can try adding this before your mail command:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
ini_set("username","<myaccount.gmail.com>"); # You need to change this
ini_set("password","YOUR_PASSWORD"); # You need to change this
```

I haven't tested these settings, but it should send you in the right direction.